# Teradata inbuilt ER diagram generator

Tags: teradata

Does teradata have an inbuilt way of generating ER diagrams of databases within it? If so, can you tell me how to do it?

I can't use third party tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any tools offered by Teradata that support the generation of ER diagrams. You will need to consider tools such as ERwin from Computer Associates or ER/Studio from Embarcadero. (***Not endorsing either of these products, merely offering them as examples.***)

There may be some other Open Source tools that support ER Diagrams but I am not familiar with them.

Comment: I don't have admin rights on my system. I can't install third party tools. Is there any other way? What about visio? But I'm not able to find teradata driver in it. I don't want to use the generic odbc driver as it doesn't generate relationships.

Comment: If you don't have admin rights to install software such as ERwin then you won't be able to install Teradata ODBC or .Net Provider software either.